# str_replace not replacing string on mail send

Tags: php, str-replace

I'm trying to use `str_replace()` to insert the users name when sending out the email. It's not working, am I missing something? The email is processed but `<!--{Username}-->` is not replaced with `$en['user']` variable

```
        $text_content = file_get_contents('emails/welcome_txt.tpl');
        $html_content = file_get_contents('emails/welcome.tpl');

        $body = "--$mime_boundary\n";
        $body.= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"charset=us-ascii\"\n";
        $body.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";
        $body.= str_replace("<!--{Username}-->",$en['user'],$text_content);
        $body.= "\n\n";

        $body.= "--$mime_boundary\n";
        $body.= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n";
        $body.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";    
        $body.= str_replace("<!--{Username}-->",$en['user'],$html_content);
        $body.= "\n\n";
        $body.= "--$mime_boundary--\n";
```

Comment: I suggest a bit of printf debugging.  Print out the variables before and after that line and see what's what.

Comment: Meaning that the email still containts `<!--{Username-->` or that the replacement left the username blank? Note that `str_replace()` as you posted, **will** work if `$en['user']` isset and the text contains the placeholders

Comment: @hek2mgl `<!--{Username-->` remained

Comment: @acctman is this a typo in your comment or are you missing the `}` ?

Comment: @hek2mgl typo. it works fine when I do `printf`